# Vector Space Proofs

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $B = \{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is linearly independent, prove that any subset of $B$ is linearly independent.

How would I prove this question?

Comment: Try it first with $n = 3$.  If the general proof doesn't come to you, examine a few examples with $n=3$.  Throughout all these efforts, make sure you clearly understand the definition of linear independence.

Answer (score 1):

if $B = \{v_1,...,v_n\}$ are linearly independent, then there is no set of scalars $\{c_1,\cdots, c_n\}$ such that $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots+c_nv_n = 0$ other than the trivial $c_1=c_2=\cdots = c_n = 0$

If we take a subset of $B$ it would be the equivalent of setting some subset of $\{c_1,\cdots, c_n\}$ to $0.$

Nonetheless, there is no still no set $\{c_1,\cdots, c_n\}$ such that $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots+c_nv_n = 0$ other than the trivial set.